# WPdb not working in custom plugin

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I am trying to use wpdb in a plugin file but for some reason I not getting errors just no result.

I am just wanting to get some information from a table and display it to end user any ideas as to why its not working

```
 function show_forminfo(){
     global $wpdb;
     $sql =  "SELECT * FROM 4hSIc_pods_player_ranking WHERE player_id='".$playerId."'";
     $clientRow = $wpdb->get_row( $wpdb->prepare($sql));
    echo $clientRow->points_to_redeem;
        echo "<div id='infopoints' class='modal fade' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='myModalLabel' aria-hidden='true'>";
        echo "<div class='modal-dialog'>";
        echo "<div class='modal-content'>";
        echo "<div class='modal-header'>";
        echo "<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-hidden='true'>×</button>";
        echo "<h4 class='modal-title'>Redeem Points</h4>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<form class='form-horizontal'  class='contact' name='redemmpointsForm' id='redemmpointsForm' >";
        echo " <div class='form-group'>";
        echo "<h3>You have points pending:<br />";
        echo "".$clientRow->points_to_redeem;
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='playerid' value='<?php echo $playerId;;?>' />";
        echo "     </div>";
        echo "    <div class='form-group'>";
        echo "            <div class='col-md-6'>";
        echo "     <a href='#' class='btn btn-info' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</a>";
        echo "         </div>";
        echo "      </div>";
        echo "</form>";
        echo "      </div>";
        echo "      </div>";
        echo "      </div>";

    }
```

Comment: This [url](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/basic-wpdb-query-not-working-no-results) may solve your issue

Answer (score 1):

You need to include wp-load.php

```
    require( '/path/to/wp-load.php' );
```

Comment: this is a incorrect answers worpdress states do not include wp-load

Comment: very mature when ur going against wordpress documentation of a down vote !

Comment: What you mean due to down vote? I have not voted. Did you try to check
$wpdb->show_errors( true ) and $wpdb->last_query  to show deeper?